# How to include .env file in tsconfig.json for transpiler

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a typescript project structure like this:

```bash
root/
  app/
    index.ts
  config/
    .env.dev
```

Inside index.ts, I want to call `dotenv.config()` with the path pointing to the `.env.dev` file to configure it:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

// set __dirname, yada yada yada
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

// NODE_ENV is defined manually to NODE_ENV=dev
const dotenvPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', `config/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
dotenv.config({
  path: dotenvPath,
});

console.log(`dotenvPath: ${dotenvPath}`)
console.log(`${process.env.SOMEVAR_INSIDE_ENVDEV_FILE}`) // <-- undefined
```

However, when I try to use `process.env.SOMEVAR_INSIDE_ENVDEV_FILE`, it is undefined.

The line `` console.log(`dotenvPath: ${dotenvPath}`) `` outputs:

```
dotenvPath: C:\Users\myuser\path\to\project\.build\config\.env.dev
```

However, `.build\config\` seems to not exist. This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./app"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Adding the following tag after `"exclude"` tag:

```json
"include": [
    "./config/*",
 ],
```

gives me a weird error that I could not find much about: `Error: [{"messageText":"No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '[\"./config/*\"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[\"node_modules\"]'.","category":1,"code":18003}]`. Only resource I found was [this](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/302), but it doesn't make much sense in my case, because I find nothing wrong with what I did.

**How can I force typescript to include my `./config/.env.dev` file into the transpilation process, so that I can access it during runtime?**

Comment: What would TypeScript do with a file like that?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I want to read the `.env` file from inside the `index.ts`... how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript only transpiles Typescript files and potentially Javascript files. If you just want to write a script that copies a file if it has changed, this seems like a good problem for adopting a build tool like Make.

Comment: So there is no way to include .env files in the typescript build? How is this problem usually solved?

Comment: @Bersan `cp`,  `make` or other build tools.